# WiX-Generated installer shows bootstrapper EULA dialog in quiet mode

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, .net-client-profile

I'm using WiX to generate an installer with a bootstrapper for the .NET 4 Client Profile. However, while the individual components each have a "quiet" mode (the generated MSI and the .NET 4 installer), attempting to install using the generated Setup.exe in quiet mode still shows the EULA dialog for the .NET Client Profile. The dialog appears to be coming from the generated Setup.exe, as it has the name of my generated installer in the title bar. Additionally, the help options for the generated Setup.exe don't specifically mention a "quiet" mode, even though the components it wraps do.

Is there a way to run this setup.exe in a quiet or non-interactive mode?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you are allowed to install it without the EULA showing - check that first.

But take a look at `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\DotNetFX40Client\en`. The package.xml describes (part of) the bootstrapper.

The `<Package LicenseAgreement="eula.rtf"` part is used to determine whether or not to show the eula. The arguments of the installer used in the `product.xml` make sure the eula is not shown again during installation. So I think you can create your own bootstrapper package, tweak it a bit to not show the eula, give it a different ProductCode and use that to install.

Note, in the `<RelatedProducts>` you should add:

```
<IncludesProduct Code=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client" />
```

to make sure dependencies are being met of other (bootstrapper) packages requiring the .NET 4 Client Profile.

Comment: This was a pretty neat/slick trick - unfortunately, instead of removing the dialog completely, the EULA dialog is replaced with a "do you want to install this?" dialog.

Comment: I am not able to test this right now, but you can try if setup.exe accepts command line arguments; probably `setup.exe /q` but `/passive` is also possible. I am afraid the only other option is to create your own bootstrapper launcher (setup.exe).

Comment: Yeah, I've tried all sorts of combinations of /q, /quiet, /passive, /silent, /s, etc, nothing seemed to do it. There is a /? that shows help, and it makes no mention of a quiet/non-interactive mode.